# How to change webView to Desktop version with Android Studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-webview

So, I am working on an app and the website that the webView is loading loads up in the mobile version. But the problem is that I want the desktop version loaded instead. I have searched everywhere, but it does not load.

Any thoughts? Anything helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change user agent

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
    webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just changing user agent does not worked add this line to

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```